# Using `bsxfun` for non-numeric data

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

Is there an equivalent to `bsxfun` for non-numeric data?

For example, I want to compare all pairs of strings stored in two cell-arrays:

```
>> a = {'aa', 'bb', 'cc'};
>> b = {'dd', 'aa'};
>> bsxfun( @strcmp, a, b' ); % not working for cells :-(
```

Comment: I always end up looping...You can try to submit this enhancement request to TMW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no such equivalent for cell-arrays :-(

As far as I can see, you can either:

1. Follow Oleg's suggestion and use loops
2. Use existing implementations such as [`mAryCellFcn`](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23409-multidimensional-cell-based-bsxfun-generalization) <strike>or [`csxfun`](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19371-csxfun)</strike> from the File Exchange.
3. Roll your own function. For example, here's a variant of Robert's idea that works for inputs of any dimensions (under the restrictions of `bsxfun`, of course) and an arbitrary binary function `func`:

   ```
   function C = mybsxfun(func, A, B)
       idx_A = reshape(1:numel(A), size(A));
       idx_B = reshape(1:numel(B), size(B));
       C = bsxfun(@(ii, jj)func(A(ii), B(jj)), idx_A, idx_B);
   ```

   If your function can operate on entire cell arrays element-wise, you could perform a singleton expansion on your cell arrays first, and then feed them directly to the function `func`:

   ```
   mask = bsxfun(@or, true(size(A)), true(size(B)));
   idx_A = bsxfun(@times, mask, reshape(1:numel(A), size(A)));
   idx_B = bsxfun(@times, mask, reshape(1:numel(B), size(B)));
   C = func(A(idx_A), B(idx_B));
   ```

   The latter method might be faster if `func` is optimized for vectorized operations on cell arrays.

Comment: `csxfun` is no good; that's just `cellfun` and nothing else.  `mAryCellFcn` looks good though...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Thanks for noticing that!

Comment: @RobertP. Thanks. The underlying idea is your though!

Answer (score 4):

I like [Rody's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17092000/2338750), but you *could* also do a workaround like this:

```
ia=(1:length(a)).'; ib=1:length(b);
a=a(:);
bsxfun(@(ii,jj) strcmp(  a(ii),b(jj) )  ,ia, ib);
```

Comment: +1. This wouldn't give the correct dimensions for 2D/3D arrays. However, I did adapt your question to works on cell arrays just like the original `bsxfun` (hope you don't mind).

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
[str,ia,ib] = intersect(a,b)
```

?

Comment: (but then again, I guess Shai is looking for a general approach that could substitute `bsxfun` for more than just comparing these strings)

Comment: @RobertP. - you are right. I was using `strcmp` as an example.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, broadcasting only works for numeric types. Here are other possible alternatives:

```
a = {'aa', 'bb', 'cc'};
b = {'dd'; 'aa'};

%# obviously doesnt work
%#bsxfun(@strcmp, a, b)

%# do the singleton expansion ourselves
strcmp(repmat(a,size(b)), repmat(b,size(a)))

%# if you dislike REPMAT, we can use Tony's trick
strcmp(a(ones(size(b)),:), b(:,ones(size(a))))

%# we could also use CELLFUN
cell2mat(cellfun(@(s)strcmp(a,s), b, 'UniformOutput',false))
```