# Matlab: Looking to find a way to generalize bsxfun for functions that take in two vectors and output a scalar

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

For example, given X, a list N of points in R^d, (Nxd matrix). Then X = [x_1;x_2;...;x_N]. I want to compute the distance matrix D (and NxN matrix) between points {x_i}.

If d = 1 I can use `bsxfun`:

```
D = bsxfun(dist,X,X')
```

Where `dist` is defined on scalars by `dist = @(x_i,x_j) sqrt( sum((x_i-x_j).^2) )`. For d = 1, `dist` takes in two scalars and outputs a scalar, so `bsxfun` may be applied.

What I want to do is to have this make since for general d. That is, I need a function like bsxfun that can work when dist takes in two vectors and outputs a scalar.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: For distances, have you checked `pdist2`?

Comment: It would be more clear if you included an example. Are you saying you want to take an n-by-d matrix, and find the distance for each pair of rows resulting in a symmetrical n-by-n (i.e. what `pdist2` does)?

Comment: pdist2 would solve the example I mentioned, but I would ultiamtely like this to work whenever I expand XX^T where X is a vector that may contain non numerical information.

Comment: Why don't you use a for loop? The for loop could also be included in the "dist" function, if you nest its definition (or if you put it in a separate file)

Comment: These solutions might be relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/a/23911671/3293881 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/24345847/3293881

Comment: @student you may also find this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/17091071/1714410 inspiring.