# to find mean square error of two cell arrays of different sizes

Tags: matlab, block, cell-array, mse

I have two cell arrays. One is 'trans_blk' of size <232324x1> consists of cells of size <8x8> and another 'ca' is of size <1024x1> consists of cells of size <8x8>. 
I want to compute mean square error (MSE) for each cell of 'ca' with respect to every cell of 'trans_blk'.

I used the following code to compute:

```
m=0;
for ii=0:7
    for jj=0:7

        m=m+((trans_blk{:,1}(ii,jj)-ca{:,1}(ii,jj))^2);

    end
end

m=m/(size of cell);    //size of cell=8*8
disp('MSE=',m);
```

Its giving an error. Bad cell reference operation in MATLAB.

Comment: I think the error is because of the indexing of the cell. `{:,1}`<- not sure if this is rigth...

Comment: Another issue is that matlab indexes start with 1 not 0. Your loop iterates from 0:7 not 1:8.

Comment: Could you tell what it says when you type `class(trans_blk{1})` at console? also for `class(ca{1})`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ways that I figured you could go:

```
% First define the MSE function
mse = @(x,y) sum(sum((x-y).^2))./numel(x);
```

I'm a big fan of using `bsxfun` for things like this, but unfortunately it doesn't operate on cell arrays.  So, I borrowed the singleton expansion form of the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090047/using-bsxfun-for-non-numeric-data).

```
% Singleton expansion way:
mask = bsxfun(@or, true(size(A)), true(size(B))');
idx_A = bsxfun(@times, mask, reshape(1:numel(A), size(A)));
idx_B = bsxfun(@times, mask, reshape(1:numel(B), size(B))');

func = @(x,y) cellfun(@(a,b) mse(a,b),x,y);

C = func(A(idx_A), B(idx_B));
```

Now, if that is a bit too crazy (or if explicitly making the arrays by `A(idx_A)` is too big), then you could always try a loop approach such as the one below.

```
% Or a quick loop:
results = zeros(length(A),length(B));
y = B{1};
for iter = 1:length(B)
  y = B{iter};
  results(:,iter) = cellfun(@(x) mse(x,y) ,A);  
end
```

If you run out of memory: Think of what you are allocating: a matrix of doubles that is (232324 x 1024) elements.  (That's a decent chunk of memory. Depending on your system, that could be close to 2GB of memory...)

If you can't hold it all in memory, then you might have to decide what you are going to do with all the MSE's and either do it in batches, or find a machine that you *can* run the full simulation/code on.

**EDIT**
If you only want to keep the sum of all the MSEs (as OP states in comments below), then you can save on memory by

```
% Sum it as you go along:
results = zeros(length(A),1);
y = B{1};
for iter = 1:length(B)
  y = B{iter};
  results = results + cellfun(@(x) mse(x,y) ,A);  
end
results =sum (results);
```

Comment: I'd probably replace A to be `ca` and B to be `trans_blk`, though I don't think it would matter which way you do it. Maybe you could test to see which would be faster?

Comment: Above all answers gives error of 'out of memory'. Please let me know any other method to solve my problem.

Comment: What do you want to do with the MSE's after you have them computed?  Do you want to add up all of the MSE's? Do you want to produce a histogram?

Comment: Yes I'll have to add up all of them.

Comment: If my answer had helpful in answering your question,  you might mask it as the accepted answer.